# Display Ballon Tip on Button Click

Tags: c#, tooltip

I want to display a ballon tip when an error occures instead of showing MessageBox.

[NOTE] i did not want it to be shown on mouse Hover.

I tried both but they actually show the tip on mouse hover

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip();
toolTip1.Show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ToolTip Popup event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.popup.aspx) to check if there is a Tooltip present and cancel it if there isn't. You can then set the tooltip during your validation then show it. In this example I set a timer to reset the tooltip text after a 2 second timeout.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;
        toolTip1.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(toolTip1_Popup);
        toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox1, "");
    }

    void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (toolTip1.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl) == "")
            e.Cancel = true;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        toolTip1.RemoveAll();

    }

    private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        int temp;
        if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp))
            showTip("Validation Error", (Control)sender);

    }

    private void showTip(string message, Control destination)
    {
        toolTip1.Show(message, destination);
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You know the ballon that appears when you turn on caps lock in a password textbox ?, i want to do something like that i think you miss understood me. or i misunderstood you.

Comment: @RuneS The code that I gave you will prevent the tooltip from showing on mouseover, it will show on validation error. Are far as the specifics of the cap lock message I will have to look onto it

Comment: @MarkHall Wouldn't it be better to disable the tooltip instead of trying to hide it when it tries to show? I think ToolTipService.IsEnabled = false would do the trick.

Comment: @MikeKulls I am actually handling the event, to prevent it from showing except when there is an actual tooltip assigned, that is why I am removing all of the tooltips in order to have a known quantity to check. One thing I found out that if the Tooltip is equal to "" it will not show, so the Popup event is redundent and can be done away with.

Answer (score 0):

Much to my surprise it appears that toolTip1.IsOpen = true will show a tooltip and allow it to stay open. Note that you will need to provide code to close it because it wouldn't go away on its own on my machine no matter what I did.